# What will happen if I intend to display the hidden surface after clearing the window, draw the game objects, and then display the window again?

Tags: sfml, draw-order, double-buffering

What will happen if I intend to display the hidden surface after clearing the window, draw the game objects, and then display the window again? Am I watching the drawing process of the objects? Is this process a graphical glitch? Is it bad only for the aesthetic or bad for the system?

```
window.clear();
window.display();
window.draw(spriteBackground);
window.draw(spritePlayer);
window.display();
```

Comment: What does the documentation about display says? What are the results of you trying this? SFML is open source, did you check the underlying code of the function?

Comment: Oh, I got it, Vaillancourt.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-draw.php) (emphasis mine):

> This **clear/draw/display** cycle is the **only good way** to draw things.
> **Don't try other strategies**, such as keeping pixels from the previous
> frame, "erasing" pixels, or drawing once and calling display multiple
> times. You'll get strange results due to double-buffering.